# Selecting dynamically an option using jquery

Tags: jquery, performance, select

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/989Zp/7/).

Rules :

- If ".adminBox" is checked, `input[value='admin']` must be selected.
- If not, `input[value='sei']` must be.

I've tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/989Zp/7/), but this wouldn't work.

Any brilliant idea, please ?

Comment: Where is `if ($("input[name='adminBox']")` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few observations

- Need to listen to the input with class `adminBox`, not to all checkboxes
- Use the checked property to see whether it is checked
- `adminBox` is a class not name
- use .val() to set the value of the select element

It should be

```
$("input.adminBox").change(function () {
    if (this.checked){
        $("#role").val('admin');
    } else {
        $("#role").val('sei');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4kZNb/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        var that = $(this);
        if(this.checked)
        {
            if(that.hasClass('adminBox'))
            {
               $('#role').val('admin');
            }

            else
            {
                 $('#role').val('sei');
            }
        }

        else
        {
             $('#role').val('sei');
        }
    });
```